# Evaluating R.id.home

Tags: android, constants

I was following this tutorial here - http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html - for implementing the Up Navigation. Sort of the same as the user pressing the Back button on the phone, but the onBackPressed() method does not fire when the 'Up' button is pressed. In the tutorial they show that you trap R.id.home in the onOptionsItemSelected() method. This web page - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id.html - shows that the value of R.id.home should equal 16908332, but it doesn't in my app. In the code below if I use R.id.home it fails. If I hard-code in 16908332 it works. For me R.id.home evaluates to 21312330724. According to the page, all of the R.id values begin 1690. I hate hard-coding in a value for a built-in value, but I'm not sure what else to do. Could this cause problems down the road? Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug?

Greg

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.home) {//16908332
        Intent upIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);

        upIntent.putExtra(CAT_ID, CatID);
        upIntent.putExtra(USER_ID, UserID);
        upIntent.putExtra(LIST_ID, ListID);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, upIntent);
        NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: Notice that you should compare your id to `android.id.home`, not your custom R.id.home variable, if you have one. Check your R import namespace on the upper part of your class. If you have your custom R import there, you have to strictly define your id as android.id.home.

Comment: Thanks. What worked was android.R.id.home. This is a new activity that has almost nothing in it, especially no custom R.id.home variable. The only imports are content.Intent, support.v4.app.NavUtils, support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity, os.Bundle, view.Menu, view.MenuItem, widget.Toast

Answer (score 27):

You need to compare it to the android one:

```
if (id == android.R.id.home){
    ...
}
```